# Wget not run from java programm

Tags: java, macos, terminal, wget

I am writing script witch need to call wget with:

```
    String url = "https://someurl.com/"
    String cookies = "/home/cookie_file.txt/"
    String command = "wget  --load-cookies " + cookies + " -U \"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36\" -e robots=off --reject '*.js,*.css,*.ico,*.txt,*.gif,*.jpg,*.jpeg,*.png,*.mp3,*.pdf,*.tgz,*.flv,*.avi,*.mpeg,*.iso' --ignore-tags=img,link,script --header=\"Accept: text/html\" -r -np " + url ;
    Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
```

When I run the command from terminal everything is ok is working fine but when I run it from java file is starting and exiting after a second and no output is issued.Do I missing something?
I am on Ubuntu but the script also need to work on Mac OS also when i run with sudo from jar file same result.

This is the proc.info()

```
[user: Optional[myuser], cmd: /usr/bin/wget, args: [-c, --load-cookies, 76e181c7-78d4-4e7a-8f3b-10e6a04905b6.txt, -U, "Mozilla/5.0, (X11;, Linux, x86_64), AppleWebKit/537.36, (KHTML,, like, Gecko), Chrome/51.0.2704.103, Safari/537.36", -e, robots=off, --reject, '*.js,*.css,*.ico,*.txt,*.gif,*.jpg,*.jpeg,*.png,*.mp3,*.pdf,*.tgz,*.flv,*.avi,*.mpeg,*.iso', --ignore-tags=img,link,script, --header="Accept:, text/html", -r, -np, https://www.url.com], startTime: Optional[2021-12-03T13:27:19.470Z], totalTime: Optional[PT0S]]
```

Comment: The output is written into pipes you can read, e.g. via `proc.getInputStream()`. If you don’t want that but rather write the output into the same console as your Java process, use `String[] command = { "wget", "--load-cookies", cookies, "-U", "Mozilla/5.0 … Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36", "-e", "robots=off", "--reject", "'*.js,*.css,*.ico,*.txt,*.gif,*.jpg,*.jpeg,*.png,*.mp3,*.pdf,*.tgz,*.flv,*.avi,*.mpeg,*.iso'", "--ignore-tags=img,link,script", "--header=Accept: text/html", "-r", "-np", url }; Process proc = new ProcessBuilder(command).inheritIO().start();`

Comment: Yes I just found this also and its work with String[] array. Thank you